# Polygonized a land use map (raster) in QGIS but the output is just a black shapefile. How do I fix this?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, saga, polygonize

So, I have a land use map that I need to digitize. The changes in the map is very fine so it will take a long time to manually digitize it. When I used the Raster > Conversion > *Polygonize (Raster to Vector)* function, the output shapefile is just black. I tried bands 1 to 4 but same result.

I also tried SAGA's *Raster values to points* and GRASS' *r.to.vect* but the result is the same: a black shapefile.

Can anyone help?

[image: saga]

[image]

Comment: If it is a picture composed of three bands (RGB color), then polygonize will not work. You need to digitize the land use map manually.

Comment: Didn't know that. Idk if this is obvious then what type of raster would the function work if it doesnt accept RGB colors? Thanks, @ahmadhanb.

Comment: polygonize works with single band raster not multi-band raster.